# SQL statement for linking table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

```
collection
==========
collection_id (primary key)
collection_name
collection_type

collectable
===========
collectable_id(primary key)
collectable_name
collectable_type
collectable_collection
```

What is the SQL statement so that `collectable_collection` can only take as input `collection_id`? Sorry if this is too simple. Is this a change specific to the column: `collectable_collection` or to the table: `collectable`?

I am using a MySQL database .

Comment: The answer is going to be based on th database you are using. E.g. MySql, Oracle,  Sql Server, etc

Comment: Ok you might want to update the tag as well. People use the tags as filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be better if you implement this in the application level than with the SQL. Just check if the `id` to be inserted in the `collectable_collection` is a `collection_id` and then perform the insert operation, if the `collectable_collection` has more than one `collection_id`'s.

**EDIT**

If the `collectable_collection` has only one id in it, then you can use `Foreign Key`. Check the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), for more info on how to use it

Comment: I dont think the relation you need can be implemented using SQL, cos if `collectable_collection` can have only one `id` then you can go for `foreign key`, but acc to the name i think the field is supposed to have more than one id

Comment: it can actually be any collection_id, how can I implement Foreign key, I just started learning SQL, so sorry if this is too obvious

Comment: ya, it can be any `collection_id`, but will it contain only one `collection_id` or more than one???. If it is only one use `foreign key` else do a manual check before inserting

Comment: it would contain only one collection_id

Comment: The `foreign key` is the way to go. Check the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) for more info. :)

Answer (score 0):

use coolection-id as a foreig key in the collectable table this will do insertion only when collection_id would be persent in the collection table.

And if u want to insert multi values then make a log table for collection and that will be use to get collection values in collectable table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a database management tool, such as the official [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). There you can use the user interface to make any change to the database.

If you wish to use SQL instead, you could use the following:

```
ALTER TABLE collectable
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_collectable_collection
FOREIGN KEY (collectable_collection)
REFERENCES collection (collection_id)
```

Optionally, you could add `ON DELETE CASCADE` or `ON DELETE SET NULL` to automaticly remove the affected rows in the `collectable` table or set the references to `NULL` when a row in the `collection` table are removed.